# Given a survival rate matrix, describe what can be said about it

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, statistics, matrix-equations

Given this matrix equation:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
        c_{k+1} \\
        t_{k+1} \\
        a_{k+1} \\
        \end{bmatrix}      =    \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 0.33 \\
        0.18 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0.71 & 0.94 \\
        \end{bmatrix}   \begin{bmatrix}
        c_k \\
        t_k \\
        a_k \\
        \end{bmatrix}$$

where $c_k$ represents the female child population, $t_k$ represents the female teen population, and $a_k$ represents the female adult population of a species of animal. There is no given starting population.

**From this matrix equation, what can be said about the long term survival of the species?**

I know it will obviously die out from doing some basic algebra. I just don't know how to prove it given that 2 eigenvalues and eigenvectors for A are imaginary and I don't know what to do with imaginary eigen-pairs.

**Can you suggest an increase in the survival rate of teens which would result in an increase of the species population?**

This I managed to estimate to be around 25.5%, but that isn't the exact answer and it was using a roundabout way. I'm sure there is a much easier way to find this out, just not sure how.

*Any direction on how to just approach the problems would be appreciated*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the matrix (in general, let's say $n \times n$) is $A$ and the initial population vector ${\bf v}$, after $k$
generations the population vector is $A^k {\bf v}$.  If there are $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors 
 ${\bf u}_j$ and $\lambda_j$, we have
${\bf v} = \sum_j c_j {\bf u}_j$, and $A^k {\bf v} = \sum_j c_j \lambda^k {\bf u}_j$.  If all eigenvalues have absolute value $< 1$, the population will certainly die out as $k \to \infty$.  If there is at least one eigenvalue with absolute value $\ge 1$, it can survive.
This is still true in the "defective" case with fewer than $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors, but slightly more complicated to prove.

By the Perron-Frobenius theorem, for a matrix with nonnegative entries the eigenvalue with largest absolute value is positive.  So basically you're interested in positive roots of the characteristic polynomial.

If you replace the $0.18$ in your matrix with $r$, the characteristic polynomial
becomes $\lambda^3 - 0.94 \lambda^2 - 0.2343 r$.  $\lambda = 1$ would satisfy this for $r = .06/.2343 \approx 0.2560819462$.